# Multiprocessing, specific order

Tags: python, multiprocessing, semaphore

I have question for you guys.

So, my goal is to start 5 processes. Each of those have to print their name via a function. The last thing, there aren't an any race conditions allowed.
I have to achieve this all with semaphores.
The order of execution should be like this:

start p1 -> p1 end -> p2 and p3 -> p2 and p3 end -> start p4 -> p4 end -> p5

Here is what I have so far:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Semaphore
import time

def start (processName):
    semaphore.acquire()
    print(processName)
    time.sleep(1)
    semaphore.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    semaphoreSize = 1
    semaphore = Semaphore(semaphoreSize)

    p1 = Process (target = start, args= ('Process 1',))
    p2 = Process (target = start, args= ('Process 2',))
    p3 = Process (target = start, args= ('Process 3',))
    p4 = Process (target = start, args= ('Process 4',))
    p5 = Process (target = start, args= ('Process 5',))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p5.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    p5.join()
```

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: "I have to achieve this all with semaphores." Semaphores themselves are *not ordered*. An acquire operation decrements the count, blocking and waiting if the count goes to zero, returning when the count is greater than zero, all atomically. (A release atomically increments.) They essentially tell you: "Is resource X is still available? If so, take one and let me proceed, if not, wait until it is." So, what resource or resources can your five processes wait for? Will a single resource ("anyone may proceed") suffice, given that there's no implied ordering for who *gets* the resource?

Comment: Ok, so basically it's not possible for semaphores themselves to accomplish a specific order of process execution. But is it possible with help of semaphores to get something like this: if not process 1 is in queue(of the semaphore) -> set process to sleep -> get another process into the queue for check ?

Comment: Given that this looks like homework, I'm not going to just give you the answer, but think about this in terms of what's shared and what's private. How *many* shared things can/must you set up to arrange for five independent entities—think of them as Alice, Bob, Carol, Dave, and Ellen, perhaps—to carefully take turns in alphabetical (or numeric) order? How can you arrange things so that when Dave says "I am done, you go now", he means specifically *Ellen* can go now? (If you share more than *just* one or more semaphores, there are multiple solutions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help torek!

My solution looks like this now:

```
def start(processName):
    if processName == 'Process 1':
        semaphore1.acquire()
        print(processName)
        time.sleep(1)
        semaphore2.release()
        semaphore3.release()
    elif processName == 'Process 2':
        semaphore2.acquire()
        print(processName)
        time.sleep(1)
        semaphore4.release()
    elif processName == 'Process 3':
        semaphore3.acquire()
        print(processName)
        time.sleep(1)
        semaphore4.release()
    elif processName == 'Process 4':
        semaphore4.acquire()
        semaphore4.acquire()
        print(processName)
        time.sleep(1)
        semaphore5.release()
    else:
        semaphore5.acquire()
        print(processName)
        time.sleep(1)
        semaphore5.release()
```